# Code Igniter Pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

My Link: `http://asdasd.com/*****/****/urunler?kategori=5`

I need to add pagination to my page.

My Code:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/asd/urunler?kategori='.$kateg;
$config['total_rows'] = $this->anime_model->kategorisayi($kateg);
$config['per_page'] = 3; 
$config['first_link'] = '<a href="#" class="prevposts">Önceki</a>';
$config['last_link'] = '<a href="#" class="nextposts">Sonraki</a>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<a href="#" class="activeposts">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

When I click pagination link, the page didnt change.

```
http://asdasd.com/yenianimesatis/index.php/anime/urunler?kategori=5/3
```

How can i fix it?

**Edit:** When I use this code

```
$config['suffix'] = '/?'.http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");
```

2nd page: `http://asasgs/yenianimesatis/index.php/anime/urunler/5/?kategori=5`, but 1st page: `http://asgasg/yenianimesatis/index.php/anime/urunler/`

It must be like this: `http://asgasg/yenianimesatis/index.php/anime/urunler/?kategori=5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I get your question.  But two things to note:

1) CI pagination will simply add /# to the end of your base url, so the place where you claim it didn't change - http://asdasd.com/yenianimesatis/index.php/anime/urunler?kategori=5**/3**, it actually did add the /# to the end.  Maybe you need to set pagination $config['enable_query_strings'] to TRUE?  Read about **enable_query_strings** here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html.

2) You say you use $config['suffix'], but I'm not sure what that is for.  Do you mean $config['url_suffix']?  If so, there may be a bug: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/161875/